# Unable to get commits list deployed by ansible and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I want to get all the commits list which is deployed by ansible.I am using this code for getting list

```
- name: Print complete log list
      command: git log --pretty=oneline "{{ cloned.after }}..{{ cloned.before }}"
      register: commits_list
```

But i am getting this error

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["git", "log", "--pretty=oneline", "192fe5aa6c1fb835297b235a19882a5ec67c7f16..c3c558b231d1591baf5e5fd76fdc5a311934a605"], "delta": "0:00:00.058074", "end": "2017-06-07 12:28:15.668605", "failed": true, "rc": 128, "start": "2017-06-07 12:28:15.610531", "stderr": "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git", "stderr_lines": ["fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

I register **cloned** to get the git information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to chdir into repo dir:

```
- name: Print complete log list
  command: git log --pretty=oneline "{{ cloned.after }}..{{ cloned.before }}"
  args:
    chdir: /path/to/cloned/ropo
  register: commits_list
```